# Exporting layer from Google My Maps as KML has no geometries

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a CSV with an address field (no lat/long), so I went to Google My Maps, imported the csv and geocoded of the records.

Now I export the layer as KML and added the KML to QGIS and Google Earth Pro, but in non of them I can see the markers. In fact in QGIS, the KML layer is added as datatable (no geometry).

What's happening? How can I export a geometry layer from google My Maps?

[image]

Comment: do you have a mymaps public link?

Comment: @Mapperz no, the info in every feature is sensitive..

Comment: That's odd, I've faced the same problem, but I was able to open the kml on Google Earth Pro, re-export it, and then it would work fine. Can you make another map with dummy data and share the link?

Answer (score 4):

MyMaps will geocode addresses and display their locations within MyMaps, but unfortunately it will not export the geocoded coordinates to KML/KMZ. There are probably a number of reasons for this, including to prevent abuse of the MyMaps geocoding capability by folks who want to bulk geocode massive numbers addresses, and therefore really should be using a  Geocoding API. There are other services out there that will geocode small numbers of addresses like this, so probably best to find one of those.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to try is via Google Earth. Before you do that:
 1. Save your excel file as .csv
 2. In Google Earth go to: File -> Import -> select your .csv file from the directory -> click "Next" (but without loosing your mind - specify some properties, depends what you have) until you go threough all options, then click finish.
 3. Wait for batch geocoding in Google Earth, which can last up to few minutes.
 4. You should have the files with geometries
[image]

5. Then  you can save it as a .kml for further manipulation.

The process is similar to the batch address geocoding, shown here:

http://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/input-a-multiple-address-list-in-google-maps-and-google-earth-the-quickest-way/

although, I shown you the way once you have some additional info in your excel spreadsheet apart from the address only. This is why the placemarks comes from GoogleMyMaps without geometry.
Google Earth is better.