# How to import CSV with addresses (no coordinates) into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, google-mymaps

I have a CSV file with many address and I need to find the coordinates.
I think to import the CSV into [google-mymap](https://www.google.com/maps/d/) hoping that it find those points, then I would like to export a KMZ to import it in QGIS?

Am I wrong in this thought? If this is the only way to solve it, how can I find info to create this CSV file?

I imported the file into mymaps and I can see the points on the map.
Then I exported it in KML/KMZ.

When I go to layer/add layer, QGIS import only a table (with the orginal info from CSV file) not a point shape file.

In the picture below you can see information from my imported addresses KMZ (this is not a geometry point shape file) and a correct test create into mymaps.

I have to add that into mymaps app the dataset looks identical.

[image: address-to-ccordinates]

Comment: Have you done some research on geocoding?

Comment: I am doing but I am not able to write in Json / Python: I only have a csv file

Comment: if creating the CSV is the problem, I think you can also import excel tables on mymaps. mymaps asks which column contains the adresses and tries its best to geocode them

Comment: The most straight approach I may suggest is simply using [MMQGIS plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/) and then in QGIS `MMQGIS > Geocode > Geocode CSV with Web Service`. Check this artcile https://www.gislounge.com/how-to-geocode-addresses-using-qgis/

Comment: This issue has been covered in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298570/exporting-layer-from-google-my-maps-as-kml-has-no-geometries

Answer (score 4):

There is an Excel-Plugin for the OpenCage Geocoder: https://opencagedata.com/. In the free version, you have 2,500 requests/day for free. You can simply use a formula in any Excel-cell, referring to the cell where you have your address. Let's say you have in cell A1 the following string:

> 5th avenue, 12, New York City

In any other cell, introduce the forumula `=fgeocode(A1)`
The resulting output will be:

> 40.7325633; -73.9965265

See here for the tutorial: https://opencagedata.com/tutorials/geocode-in-excel

Comment: this is very powerfull...but it doe not works with address like corner between two streets ("street 1 & street 2" works with google mymaps)